# join produces 2 rows instead of one

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables that have the exact same fields and I want to join them based on a dummy field I added to them both called join2 = 1.

However when I use the below syntax, it puts it all on one line, where as I want them on seperate lines based on the name field

The syntax I used is:

```
select a.NAME, a.COUNT1, a.MIN1,a.MAX1,a.SUM1,a.AVG1,
b.NAME, b.COUNT1, b.MIN1,b.MAX1,b.SUM1,b.AVG1
from #AMT_PAYMENTS a 
INNER join #cur_bal b on (a.join2 = b.join2)
```

so the table looks like

```
name count1 min1 max1 sum1 avg1 name count1 min1 max1 sum1 avg1
```

instead of just

```
name count1 min1 max1 sum1 avg1
```

with the names listed separately vertically

Comment: This is the normal behavior; the result shows the corresponding fields from both joined tables.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you want to achieve? An example with input and expected output would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a UNION statement:

```
select a.NAME, a.COUNT1, a.MIN1,a.MAX1,a.SUM1,a.AVG1
FROM #AMT_PAYMENTS a
UNION
select b.NAME, b.COUNT1, b.MIN1,b.MAX1,b.SUM1,b.AVG1
FROM #cur_bal b
```

Comment: +1  - And if the OP wants to "keep them together" you may want to ORDER BY join2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.NAME, a.COUNT1, a.MIN1,a.MAX1,a.SUM1,a.AVG1
from #AMT_PAYMENTS a
union all
select b.NAME, b.COUNT1, b.MIN1,b.MAX1,b.SUM1,b.AVG1
from #cur_bal b
```

Comment: How does this satisfy the desired JOIN condition?

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - Hard to say if the join on the "dummy field I added to them both called join2 = 1." is really needed without more info about the data. My *guess* is that there is only one row in each temporary table. I will soon find out when OP tries the query.